# How to follow C++ bit storage in Java?

Tags: java, c++, bit, operations

if I have in c++:

```
char abc[4];

abc[0] = 0xC0; //11000000 in binary

abc[1] = 0x20; //00100000 in binary

abc[2] = 0x44; //01000100 in binary

abc[3] = 0x20; //00100000 in binary
```

So how this will be stored in memory -

```
11000000 00100000 01000100 00100000 or the reverse way ??
----------------------------------- 
   0th      1st     2nd      3rd
```

In Java I am creating `Bitset abc = new Bitset(32);`

So I need to store the same values in this(same order).This may be 
modified later according to bit positions so have to be exact same way.

So `abc[32] = 0xC0204420` will do? And if I want to store 
the values in c++ way what to do??
If I am wrong then how to do this in Java...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Comment: @Erik Endianness is not an issue here.

Comment: You might be talking about endian-ness. Is endian-ness not a property of the system? Can you really change endian-ness?

Comment: @Sriram, as @unapersson says, this doesn't have anything to do with Endianess, given the data structure in C++ is an *array* of `char`s rather than say an `int`

Comment: btw - `abc[32] = 0xC0204420` is wrong, if you want to initialize - you can do something like (C++) `unsigned char abc[] = {0xC0, 0x20, 0x44, 0x20};`.

Comment: @Nim: That makes it a little clearer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Endian is not an issue. If you use `char[4]` the lowest address 0 will be first, the highest 3 will be last, so you get in memory

```
char[0] char[1] char[2] char[3]
```

whatever you do.

If you do a `int x = *(reinterpret_cast<int*>(abc))`, *then* you get different results, depending on endianness, because the (4byte-) `int` is sometimes read as `0123`, sometimes `3210` -- and I think even `2301` has been around in the 60s.

You can not put `0xC0204420` (a larger number then `127`) into the `[32]`ths position of `abc`. If you want to implement something "fast" (and dangerous) you would need a platform-depending `reinterpret_cast`. Take a look at [`hton` and `ntoh`](http://beej.us/guide/bgnet/output/html/multipage/htonsman.html).

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that will be how C++ represents the `char` array in memory.

As for the Java, it's completely arbitrary.  It depends on how *you* define the mapping between the index into your `Bitset` and the byte/bit index in the C++ "representation".  You can define this mapping any way you like, so long as you're consistent.

Comment: AFAIK, there is no direct way to set a group of bits in the `BitSet`, so this is a manual, bit-then-byte iteration operation...

Answer (score 0):

If you create `char abc[4];` and fill it character by character, then yes, in memory it will be represented as `11000000 00100000 01000100 00100000`.

The problem I see with Java BitSet is that the contents of a BitSet cannot be represented simple as a number - there is no method for it, so how would you convert 0xC0204420 to a BitSet or how would you represent a BitSet as a number like 0xC0204420? One possibility is to take every eight bits from a BitSet, make a `char` from them (using Java bitwise operators like `<<` and `|`) and then create some char array or something from them that should be equal to the earlier C++ `char[4]`.